# AngularJS: ng-show is flickering on refresh

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs

I have this code

```
<body>
    <ng-view></ng-view>
    <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.7/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ftlabs/fastclick/master/lib/fastclick.js"></script>
    <script src="js/services.js"></script>
    <script src="js/router.js"></script>
    <script src="js/interceptor.js"></script>
    <script src="js/controller.js"></script>
    <script src="js/app.js"></script>    
</body>
```

In the ng-view something like this is loaded

```
<ng-include src="'templates/navigation.html'"></ng-include>
<ng-include src="'templates/head-bar.html'"></ng-include>
<div id="main">
    <h2>{{ controller.var }}</h2>
    <div ng-show="!controller.othervar" ng-cloak>Text..</div>
</div>
```

If I reload the page sometimes the ng-show is flickering (means it is shortly shown).

**What I have tried**

I have tried:

- adding the ng-cloak tag
- adding the css code of the documentation to my stylesheet
- adding the css code of the documentation to my index.html (head-tag)
- switching the script-tags into the head
- running the app in another browser (I have now tried Firefox and Safari)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.
It was no error with ng-cloak.

The variable for showing/hiding was set in a $http response.
Hiding if the variable isn't defined fixed my problem.

Thanks for all answers.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngCloak), you should add a rule to your CSS to hide it based on the ng-cloak attribute:

```
   [ng\:cloak], [ng-cloak], .ng-cloak {
       display: none;
   }
```

We use similar tricks on the "Built with Angular" site, which you can view the source of on Github: https://github.com/angular/builtwith.angularjs.org

Hope that helps!

Comment: As I mentioned in my initial post I have already tried this code.
"What I have tried: adding the css code of the documentation to my stylesheet"

Comment: Try moving the script tag for the angularJS to the head part of the document, rather than the body.

Comment: I have already tried that too..
See "What I have tried: switching the script-tags into the head"

Comment: did you try using ng-hide in the class? JS will take it off or set it again even if its there but till JS kicks in it can sit there and use CSS to hide your div

Comment: ng-hide has the same effect.